# Issue with PDO insertion

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, pdo

I'm trying to pass an object using jQuery post. It passes alright but something goes wrong with the php code:

```
} elseif($_GET['action'] == "insertQty") {
    $obj = json_decode($_POST['param']);
    $scArr = $obj->{'data'};
    $od_id = $obj->{'id'};

    for($i = 0; $i < count($scArr); $i++){
        $pd_id = substr($scArr[$i], 5);
        $pQty = $obj->{$scArr[$i]};

        $stmt = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_order_item_test (od_id, pd_id, od_qty) VALUES (:oId, :pId, :pQty)");

        $stmt->bindParam(':oId', $od_id);
        $stmt->bindParam(':pId', $pd_id);
        $stmt->bindParam(':pQty', $pQty);

        $stmt->execute(); 
    }
}
```

`$scArr[$i]` = "prod_#" where # is some number. Therefore `substr(5) = #`.

the obj:

```
var array = getArray();  
var itemsObj = {};

itemsObj['data'] = shoppingCart;
itemsObj['id'] = data;

//for-loop here to dynamically insert data to the obj.

$.post(url, "param=" + JSON.stringify(itemsObj), "html");
```

What could not be working properly? It's most likely a problem with the first paragraph of code since the object comes out as it should be when using `alert()`.

EDIT:

`print_r($obj)`:

```
stdClass Object
(
     [data] => Array
        (
             [0] => prod_2
        )

     [id] => 1024
     [prod_2] => 8
)
```

You can pretty much guess the outpud of `$scArr` from the above...
Basically everything object-related is fine.

Comment: Do a print_r($scArr) and print_r($obj) before the loop. What does it show?

Comment: Okay adding to the main post now.

Comment: You didn't say what is going wrong. Error message?  Note that the normal way to access object properties is just `$obj->data`, not `$obj->{'data'}` which is needed only when you are building strings or variables into property names.

Comment: And we don't see where you construct `url`.  Does it properly include the `action` parameter you're accessing in PHP?

Comment: There isn't an error message... and the url is correct because I `alert()` the output of the code (As I said, I'm using the jQuery `.post()` function). Let me try what you said and see if it works.